# $.ajax not working in IE, it is fine in Firefox

Tags: ajax, jquery, get

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">  

    function funcSendSMS(numbers, smsmessage)
    {
    alert(numbers);
      var num = numbers;
      var msg = smsmessage;
  $.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    url: "http://sms.vrksolutions.com/messageapi.asp",  
    data: "username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&sender=xxxxxx&mobile="+num+"&message="+msg,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(resp){  
      // we have the response  
      alert("Server said:\n '" + resp + "'");  
    },  
    error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  
    }  
  });  
}  
</script>
<script  language="javascript">
funcSendSMS('<?php echo $phnos ?>', '<?php echo $smsmsg;?>');
</script>
```

I got below error in IE

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   GTB6.6; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Tue, 12 Apr
>   2011 13:22:58 UTC

Message: Access is denied.

Line: 138
Char: 355
Code: 0
URI: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

at this lane i found

below code in min.js file

```
A.src=b.url;if(!d){var C=false;A.onload=A.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(!C&&(!this.readyState||this.readyState==="loaded"||this.readyState==="complete"))
{C=true;c.handleSuccess(b,w,e,f);c.handleComplete(b,w,e,f);
A.onload=A.onreadystatechange=null;r&&A.parentNode&&r.removeChild(A)}}}
r.insertBefore(A,r.firstChild);return B}var J=false,w=b.xhr();
if(w){b.username?w.open(h,b.url,b.async,b.username,b.password)
:w.open(h,b.url,b.async);try{if(b.data!=null&&!l||a&&
a.contentType)w.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
```

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction? Is your application hosted on `sms.vrksolutions.com`? If not does `sms.vrksolutions.com/messageapi.asp` support JSONP? If not then you have the answer => you cannot send AJAX requests to different domains.

Comment: If this is the case the you should use cURL to send a request to the sms service. PHP has a good cURL implementation.

Comment: I got this error in IE Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2)
Timestamp: Tue, 12 Apr 2011 13:22:58 UTC


Message: Access is denied.

Line: 138
Char: 355
Code: 0
URI: http://www.activeads.in/crm/admin/jquery.min.js

Comment: Are you really putting your login/pwd in clear view in your JS ? :D

Comment: ya i given original API keys, that s working in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
     funcSendSMS('<?php echo $phnos ?>', '<?php echo $smsmsg;?>');
});
```

or

```
function Load() {
            var a = false;
            try {
                var test = $('*');
                if(test == null)
                    throw 1;
            }
            catch (e) { a = true; }
            if (a){setTimeout(Load, 300);return;}

            funcSendSMS('<?php echo $phnos ?>', '<?php echo $smsmsg;?>');
        } 
setTimeout(Load, 300);
```

Make sure you are not doing a cross domain request through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://sms.vrksolutions.com/messageapi.asp
```

I'm going to guess that it's a cross domain scripting issue. You can't do a regular AJAX call from one domain to another for security reasons. [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) should set you straight on the security issues and how to get started with JSONP.